# Moving my Request A Quote Button

Tags: product, layout

Right now I have my product pages set up with the Request A Quote Button at the bottom of the page. I'd like to move this to the top of the page, as well as get rid of the "Add to Compare" Option and "Email to a friend".

I can't not figure out which file folder I am supposed to be in. Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

http://www.minnesotacomputers.com/sun-t1000-power-supply-300-1799.html

Comment: Turn on template path hints and you will see the file you need to edit.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do one thing For figure out in which file you have to do changes then you can use magento Template path hint.

1) For That Go to Admin panel >> System >> Configuration >> Clcik on that

Go to the Developer Tab >> Click on that Change "Current Configuration Scope" to Main site

You find Debug >> Template Path Hints >> Yes

for more details

http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints-in-magento/

2) if you want to change the request a quote button to top of the page then you have to change into your theme/template/page/html/header.phtml file.

For add to compare you are not give proper path to render Images.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to remove the unnecessary links, but am unable to move the request a quote button. I looked in the header.phtml file and that wasn't the correct file

Comment: yes this is not correct file. but you mention that I want to move at header that's y i suggest header.phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these link are defined in module, just try to locate the layout file of these module, you should have a product_view or product.info section that add buttons to your product page and defines where they are.

This will help you find the solution.

Comment: Thank you, although I am having the most difficult with trying to find the correct file